# for loop in bash to get more than 1 variables to use it in one command

Tags: linux, bash

I have one text file and I need to get 2 variables from the same text and put them in one command like

```
for i in `cat TEXT | grep -i UID | awk '{print($2)}'` && 
x in `cat TEXT | grep -i LOGICAL | awk '{print($4)}'`
do 
  echo "naviseccli -h 10.1.1.37 sancopy -create -incremental -name copy_$i -srcwwn $x -destwwn xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -verify -linkbw 2048" >> OUTPUT
done
```

is there any possible way to accomplish that am storage admin and need to do tons of commands so i need to get this script to do it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You should format code without tabs (indent of 4 spaces recommended) and then select the code and hit the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it. That way, it can be made somewhat legible.

Comment: Your question is very vague. As you're obviously aware, the code that you've posted doesn't do what you want; as a result, it's not clear what you do want, so the answerers below have all made different guesses. You should clarify, by posting an example of what you expect `TEXT` to look like and, for that example, what command(s) you expect to have run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of file descriptors.  Moreover, your `cat`, `grep`, `awk` command could be combined into a single `awk` command:

```
exec 5< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/UID/ {print $2}' TEXT)
exec 6< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/LOGICAL/ {print $4}' TEXT)
while read i <&5 && read x <&6
do
  echo command $i $x         # Do something with i and x here!
done
```

Comment: it doesn't work at all it gave me error in Exec actually am not pro in the scripting so if any one can help me i will appreciate that

Comment: @user3024232 Oh, I introduced an extra space.  Fixed it.

Comment: let me ask another question if i need to add more variables like the same above so it is working but if the line less than the original text file it take only as much as the second text file? can you help me to know why?

Comment: @user3024232 Because that it what it'd do.  In that event how would you pass the parameter that is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the `cat` operations first and save the result into two arrays. Then you can iterate with an index over one array and use the same index to also access the other one.

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html about arrays in bash. Especially see the section "**Example 27-5. Loading the contents of a script into an array**".

With that resource you should be able to both populate your arrays and then also process them.

Answer (score 0):

Since your words don't have spaces in them (by virtue of the use of `awk`), you could use:

```
paste <(grep -i UID     TEXT | awk '{print($2)}') \
      <(grep -i LOGICAL TEXT | awk '{print($4)}') |
while read i x
do 
  echo "naviseccli -h 10.1.1.37 sancopy -create -incremental -name copy_$i -srcwwn" \
       "$x -destwwn xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -verify -linkbw 2048" >> OUTPUT
done
```

This uses [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to give `paste` two files which it pieces together. Each line will have two fields on it, which are read into `i` and `x` for use in the body of the loop.

Note that there is no need to use `cat`; you were eligible for a UUOC (Useless Use of `cat`) award.

Comment: actually i used this before but the out put gave me only one variables not both in the echo output!!!!!!

Comment: That could be for any of a number of reasons. There might be different numbers of lines containing UID and LOGICAL (or some of them might not have field 2 or 4). You should probably look at the output of the `paste` command and see if that's what you expect. Another less plausible option is that you've tinkered with `$IFS` in your script. You could show some sample data (say enough for 3 lines of output from `paste`) to demonstrate what's going wrong.

Comment: this is my original text     LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 50
UID:                        60:06:01:60:10:20:2E:00:24:DF:C9:2C:F4:AC:E2:11

LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 200
UID:                        60:06:01:60:10:20:2E:00:08:A5:91:23:FF:AF:E2:11

LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 30
UID:                        60:06:01:60:10:20:2E:00:BA:FF:3B:5A:2C:9A:E2:11

LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 15
UID:                        60:06:01:60:BB:10:2E:00:96:6D:0E:82:B4:09:E3:11

Answer (score 0):

Imma take a wild guess that `UID` and `LOGICAL` must be on the same line in your incoming `TEXT`, in which case this might actually make some sense and work:

```
cat TEST | awk '/LOGICAL/ && /UID/ { print $2, $4 }' | while read i x
do 
  echo "naviseccli -h 10.1.1.37 sancopy -create -incremental -name copy_$i -srcwwn" \
       "$x -destwwn xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -verify -linkbw 2048"
done
```

Comment: LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 50
UID:                        60:06:01:60:10:20:2E:00:24:DF:C9:2C:F4:AC:E2:11

LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 200
UID:                        60:06:01:60:10:20:2E:00:08:A5:91:23:FF:AF:E2:11

LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 30
UID:                        60:06:01:60:10:20:2E:00:BA:FF:3B:5A:2C:9A:E2:11

LOGICAL UNIT NUMBER 15
UID:                        60:06:01:60:BB:10:2E:00:96:6D:0E:82:B4:09:E3:11

Comment: i attached my original text file which i need to process it above

Comment: The formatting gets lost when you post as a comment. Add this text to your question.