# BASH Combination simple program to get some output

Tags: linux, bash

I have below program to access to TEXT files and get the below variables and put it in some command but actually it is not working for the if condition gave me too many argument

```
y=`grep -i UID TEXT2 | awk '{print($2)}'
exec 5< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/UID/ {print $2}' TEXT)
exec 6< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/LOGICAL/ {print $4}' TEXT)
while read i <&5 && read x <&6
do
if [ $y = $x ]
then
echo "naviseccli -h 10.1.1.37 sancopy -create -incremental -name copy_$x -srcwwn" \
   "$i -destwwn" \ "$y -verify -linkbw 2048" >> OUTPUT
else
echo " no matched UID" 
fi   
done
```

============================================================================

now it is working fine but only print 2 variables instead of 3 (i and x and y ) (x and y ) only printed now so what is the problem and i attached the new code below

```
exec 5< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/UID/ {print $2}' TEXT)
exec 6< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/LOGICAL/ {print $4}' TEXT)
exec 7< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/UID/ {print $2}' TEXT2)
exec 8< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/LOGICAL/ {print $4}' TEXT2)
if [ "$x" == "$z" ]
then
 while read i <&5 && read x <&6 i && read y <&7 && read z <&8
  echo "naviseccli -h 10.1.1.37 sancopy -create -incremental -name copy_$x -srcwwn $i        -destwwn $y -verify -linkbw 2048" >> OUTPUT
done
 else
 echo " no matched LUN number "
 fi
```

Comment: You're missing an ending backtick on the `y=` line.

Comment: And if you want to _execute_ the command in the loop, then you'd need to remove `echo`.

Comment: @devnull He doesn't want to execute it, he wants to write it into the `OUTPUT` file, which is a script that he'll execute after.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of the script. It will then display all the commands as it's executing them, and you can see the variable substitutions.

Comment: `y` could be empty. (Curious also to have a [useless use of `grep`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep) there when the following two Awk scripts are basically equivalent to this `grep | awk` script.)

Comment: exec 5< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/UID/ {print $2}' TEXT)
 exec 6< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/LOGICAL/ {print $4}' TEXT)
 exec 7< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/UID/ {print $2}' TEXT2)
 exec 8< <(awk '{IGNORECASE=1}/LOGICAL/ {print $4}' TEXT2)
 if [ "$x" == "$z" ]
 then
 while read i <&5 && read x <&6 i && read y <&7 && read z <&8
    echo "naviseccli -h 10.1.1.37 sancopy -create -incremental -name copy_$x -srcwwn $i    -destwwn $y -verify -linkbw 2048" >> OUTPUT
 done
 else
 echo " no matched LUN number "
 fi

Comment: the script as above but i can't print i and x and y variables only x and y appear i don't knoiw why?

Comment: do you have an answer for why only 2 variables instead of 3 appear when i echo ?

Comment: @user3024232: PRovide some sample of `TEXT` and `TEXT2` file data so that I can investigate and suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes here:

```
if [ "$y" = "$x" ]
```

If there are whitespace in `$x` or `$y` then quotes are necessary to make them one argument which otherwise are considered different argument by shell interpreter.

Comment: It doesn't look like they can contain whitespace due to the way he's assigning them by reading from `awk`.

Comment: It's tough to answer questions when those aren't written properly (as in don't mention what's desired).  If you look at the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159341/for-loop-in-bash-to-get-more-than-1-variables-to-use-it-in-one-command) by the OP and a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159341/for-loop-in-bash-to-get-more-than-1-variables-to-use-it-in-one-command#comment30050388_20159407) therein then it appears that the previous question asked was actually not one that was intended to be asked.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a syntax error in this line `if [ $y = $x ]
then` the correct syntax would be `if [ "$y" = "$x" ] ;
then`.

Comment: ok now i need to print three variables but only 2 appear i need to know why (the variables is (i,x and y) but i not appear

Comment: yes you can I am not sure what you want to print there is an error in the way you have handled `\"` this this will be acknowledged as a simple string

Comment: your echo statement should be something like this `echo "naviseccli -h 10.1.1.37 sancopy -create -incremental -name copy_$x -srcwwn\" \"$i -destwwn\" \"$y -verify -linkbw 2048"`
but i dont understand why you need to print something like this ""<value of $i>

Comment: maybe the value of `$i` is null

Comment: these values will be used for that command so i need to get it to input it in the command and am sure that it is output not null

Comment: can you just echo $i before this echo for testing purpose only and share its output I understand what you are trying to do dear

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down:

```
while read i <&5 && read x <&6 i && read y <&7 && read z <&8
                               ^
while                          | 
read i <&5                     |
read x <&6 i  <-- what is "i" doing here ??
read y <&7 
read z <&8
```